# Recursively loop over all files in subfolders, but not current folder

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way to re-write this batch script so that it does not search the current folder?

```
for /R %%X in (*.txt) do (
  echo %%X
)
```

So if I had a directory structure like the following

```
temp
  my_script.bat
  one.txt
  dir
    two.txt
```

When I run `my_script.bat` it will only find `two.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
for /R %%X in (*.txt) do if not "%%~dpX"=="%cd%\" echo %%~X
```